# Propagar un estado desde app --> componente padre --> componente hijo React js

Tags: reactjs, hook

Tengo un hook [id, setId] en mi app.js, necesito pasar el setId a un componente que esta dentro List.
A List se lo pasé como se ve en el código, pero no sabría como pasarlo al componente hijo.

```
 function App() {
   const [id, setId] = useState();
     return (
       <>
         <Header></Header>
          <Router>
            <Suspense fallback={<h1>Cargando...</h1>}>
              <Switch>
                 <Route path='/tenant-list'>
                   <List setId={setId}></List>
                 </Route>
              </Switch>
            </Suspense>
          </Router>
      </>
    );
    }
    
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo quieres pasar la funcion de setId lo estas pasando correctamente.
Ahora, para acceder a lo que estas enviando, puedes usar props.
Tu componente de List se deberia ver algo asi:

```
import React from 'react';
import ComponenteHijo from "../yourPath";

const List = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponenteHijo functionToSetId={props.setId} /> //aca estas enviando la funcion que pasaste desde App.js
    </div>
  );
};
export default List;
```

Y para acceder a este prop desde tu componente hijo lo haces de la sgte manera:

```
import React from 'react';

const ComponenteHijo = (props) => {

  const accessSetIdFromThisComponent = () => {
    props.functionToSetId() //Aca estas ejecutando esa funcion
  }

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponenteHijo;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Alex! Esto es exactamente lo que necesitaba saber!!

Comment: Con mucho gusto, Happy coding!